# how does v-slot works?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I don't understand the mechanism of v-slot. and how it works.how it binds to the variables.

in the code below that comes from vuetify documentation please explain this part:

```
<template v-slot:thumb-label="props">
   <span>
   {{ season(props.value) }}
   </span>
</template>
```

I dont understand what is "props" and how it connects to seasons variabe.

https://codepen.io/pumper/pen/NZZpeO

Comment: See: [Vue Documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

Answer (score 1):

The v-slot is overriding the default `thumb-label` slot and passing the `v-range-slider` value prop (props, or what is selected). It isn't connected to the `seasons` variable, instead it calls the `season()` method and passes the value of the current range.